# Что делает символ | в typescript?

Tags: typescript

Какую функцию выполняет символ | в TypeScript? Пример:

```
interface C {
  name: string | number
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Какой тип может принимать параметр name в объекте интерфейса C в данном примере? Я понимаю так что символ | работает как "или..., или...", то есть параметр name может являться как строкой так и числом.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types

Answer (score 5):

Синоним "Или"

```
name: String | number
```

означает, что `name` может принимать как строковые, так и числовые значения. И это будет корректно.